# If condition is not working for all td values?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, if-statement, conditional-statements

i am working with html table, when i check the checkbox i want to compare td values in a every tr, this condition is working fine for 1st tr from 2nd tr the condition is not working.
HTML Code -

```
<form role="form" name="conForm" id="conForm">
                    <span id="error" class="text-danger"></span>
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table id="myPTable" class="table table-xss table-hover table-bordered">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                        <th><input class="checkall" type="checkbox" name="productcheckbox"> All</</th>
                        <th class="control-label paddingtop">SI No</th>
                        <th class="control-label paddingtop">Products</th>
                        <th class="control-label paddingtop">Pending Qty</th>
                        <th class="control-label paddingtop">Quantity</th>
                        <th class="control-label paddingtop">Amount</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        <tr>
                        <td><input class="checkbox checkproduct" type="checkbox" name="check"></td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>HMIS HMIS HMIS HMIS</td>
                        <td class="availableQty">10</td>
                        <td><input  type="number" name="select[]" class="enterQty" value="10" style="width:50px;"></td>
                        <td>3000</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <td><input class="checkbox checkproduct" type="checkbox" name="check"></td>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>ERP</td>
                        <td class="availableQty">1</td>
                        <td><input  type="number" name="select[]" class="enterQty" value="1" style="width:50px;" ></td>
                        <td>9000</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <td><input class="checkbox checkproduct" type="checkbox" name="check"></td>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td>Inventory</td>
                        <td class="availableQty">10</td>
                        <td><input  type="number" name="select[]" class="enterQty" value="10" style="width:50px;"></td>
                        <td>13000</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr><td><button class="btn-info">Save</button></td></tr>
                        </tbody>
            </table>
            </form>
```

Here is the jquery code -

```
$(".btn-info").on("click",function(){
               
                var check = $('.checkproduct');              
                  if(check.is(':checked')){
                      
                      var pending="";
                      $('#myPTable tr').each(function() {
                        pending += $(this).find(".availableQty").html();    
                        console.log(pending);
                      });
                
                      var enterqty ="";
                      $('#myPTable tr').each(function() {
                        enterqty += $(this).find(".enterQty").val();
                        console.log(enterqty);
                      });

                      if(enterqty > pending){
                          $("#error").html("<p>Quantity must be less than or equal to Pending Qty</p>");                          
                      }else if(enterqty== 0){
                          $("#error").html("<p>you have checked the product please enter quantity</p>");
                        }
                              else{                          
                        var checked = $('.checkproduct:checked').size();
                      }
```

the jquery what i wrote is working for only first row, but it need to be work for every work which will be checked.now only you guys can help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: You have `=+` in the code you pasted, did you mean `+=` instead?

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi sorry typo error +=. is right.

Comment: Does that fix the problem or it still persist even with that change?

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi (enterqty== 0) this condition is not working

Comment: Basanagouda Patil, I think the problem is coming from the fact that you are declaring `enterqty` as a string, then you are trying to perform math on it as if it were a number.

Comment: `$('.checkproduct').is(':checked')` will always only compare the first one - you need to loop each row and look at the checkbox inside that row  (or loop through `:checked` as in @Carsten's answer to reparadigm your approach)

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi that would cause problem where `"12" < "2"` but would not cause the problem OP is describing - only working for first row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've reformed your code a bit, but i believe this is what you want.

```
$(".btn-info").on("click", function() {
  var pending =0;
  var enterqty=0;
  $('#myPTable .checkproduct:checked').each(function() {
    pending += (+$(this).closest('tr').find(".availableQty").text());
    enterqty += (+$(this).closest('tr').find(".enterQty").val());
  });

  if (enterqty > pending) {
    $("#error").html("<p>Quantity must be less than or equal to Pending Qty</p>");
  } else if (enterqty == 0) {
    $("#error").html("<p>you have checked the product please enter quantity</p>");
  } else {
    //var checked = $('.checkproduct:checked').size();
  }
});
```

**Demo**

```js
$(".btn-info").on("click", function() {
  var pending =0;
  var enterqty=0;
  $('#myPTable .checkproduct:checked').each(function() {
    pending += (+$(this).closest('tr').find(".availableQty").text());
    enterqty += (+$(this).closest('tr').find(".enterQty").val());
  });

  if (enterqty > pending) {
    $("#error").html("<p>Quantity must be less than or equal to Pending Qty</p>");
  } else if (enterqty == 0) {
    $("#error").html("<p>you have checked the product please enter quantity</p>");
  } else {
    //var checked = $('.checkproduct:checked').size();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form role="form" name="conForm" id="conForm">
  <span id="error" class="text-danger"></span>
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table id="myPTable" class="table table-xss table-hover table-bordered">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th><input class="checkall" type="checkbox" name="productcheckbox"> All</</th>
            <th class="control-label paddingtop">SI No</th>
            <th class="control-label paddingtop">Products</th>
            <th class="control-label paddingtop">Pending Qty</th>
            <th class="control-label paddingtop">Quantity</th>
            <th class="control-label paddingtop">Amount</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><input class="checkbox checkproduct" type="checkbox" name="check"></td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>HMIS HMIS HMIS HMIS</td>
          <td class="availableQty">10</td>
          <td><input type="number" name="select[]" class="enterQty" value="10" style="width:50px;"></td>
          <td>3000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input class="checkbox checkproduct" type="checkbox" name="check"></td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>ERP</td>
          <td class="availableQty">1</td>
          <td><input type="number" name="select[]" class="enterQty" value="1" style="width:50px;"></td>
          <td>9000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input class="checkbox checkproduct" type="checkbox" name="check"></td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>Inventory</td>
          <td class="availableQty">10</td>
          <td><input type="number" name="select[]" class="enterQty" value="12" style="width:50px;"></td>
          <td>13000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><button type="button" class="btn-info">Save</button></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: if i check all else if (enterqty == 0) condition not working.